# How to get all links that have a URL containing the same path?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to loop through the URL's found on a website to get all of those that contain the same path /item-details/ and then add these products to a set.

The issue is that many of the same product links with /item-details/ are repeated on the page but I only want the unique ones once before the try statement starts. How do I do this?

```
def FindLinks():
    links = web.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
    for link in links:
        url = (link.get_attribute("href"))
        completed = set()
        if url not in completed:
            if "item-details" in (link.get_attribute("href")):
                try:
                    driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
                    ...
```

Comment: I did not understand your question fully but you can do `completed.add(any_url)` ?  You don't even have to use `if url not in completed` because contain only unique values. Also, why are you launching a `WebDriver` inside a loop?

Comment: Thanks, that's the second driver for a popup window to scrape the product data when it's found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem but removing duplicates from a list of strings is not really related to selenium but rather a generic python issue.

To remove duplicates from a collection. of items I would generally use `set` in Python:

```py
>>> list(set([1, 2, 2, 3]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Some maybe you want to try something like:

```py
...
elements = web.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")

urls = []
for element in elements:
   urls.append(element.get_attribute("href"))

for url in list(set(urls)):
   if "item-details" in url:
      try:
         driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
...
```

Comment: Thanks but what does the variable 'all_urls' point to?

Comment: Just misspelled the name. Fixed it now.

Comment: Does my suggestion answer your question?

Comment: It did not but I upvoted it as it was helpful, thanks.